# Adding a fresh (new) instance of an object to a list

Tags: c#, list

This is a very similar problem to here [c# creating new instances of a object in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717517/c-sharp-creating-new-instances-of-a-object-in-a-for-loop) but my problem is unfortunately slightly different. I'm not using random either.

I have a setup similar to this:

```
public List<Candle> GetCandles(int can)
{
    List<Candle> dpl = new List<Candle>();

    for (int i = 0; i < can; i++)
    {
        Candle dp = new Candle();
        dp.x = new Random().Next(0000, 9999);
        dp.y = new Random().Next(0000, 9999);
        dpl.Add(dp);
    }

    return dpl;
}
```

My problem is that at the end of it, I don't have separate instances of candles inside. They're all the same candle for each element - despite me using "new" each time.

How do I make 100% sure that I'm putting a brand new candle into the list?

EDIT: Thanks to all that answered, but I was able to find out my own problem. Inside the class I was using, the variables were **static**. That meant that every single class instance had the same value. So if I set A to equal 50, all of the classes had 50.

I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, but that code wasn't mine. I'm not using random, I just posted the example because it was similar to the setup I had in my code. I had a loop and a list and was adding instances to it.

Comment: How do you find out that the candles are the same?

Comment: Also, how can you say you're not using `Random` when you are in fact using `Random`?

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that at the end of it, I don't have separate instances
>   of candles inside. They're all the same candle for each element -

Well, they are not same instances, they all have same values and the reason is the `new Random().Next`, you can fix that by declaring a `Random` instance outside the for loop and then using that for generating values.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < can; i++)
{
    Candle dp = new Candle();
    dp.x = random.Next(0000, 9999);
    dp.y = random.Next(0000, 9999);
    dpl.Add(dp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> They're all the same candle for each element - despite me using "new" each time.

No, they're not.  You *do* have different object instances at each element, each object instance simply has the same `x` and `y` values because [you're creating random numbers in a loop, all of which will have the same seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number/768001#768001).

You can trivially see that you don't have the same object instances by mutating just one of the values after the loop and seeing that only that one is different.